# php regex for line break to get rows from table in html

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a remote html file, and I am extracting a table from it.Now, I am trying to use regex to get individual rows from this table.

Here is sample format of this table:

```
<tbody style="text-align: left;">
<tr class=" even" style="text-align: left;">
<td style="text-align: left;"><a href="http://www.sdfkhy.com/%7Epbdsfby">TEXT1 </a></td>
<td style="text-align: left;">TEXT2</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">TEXT3</td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: left;">
<td style="text-align: left;"><a href="http://www.JDKSF.COM/index.html">TEXT3</a><br /><span class="style3">TEXT4</span></td>
<td style="text-align: left;">TEXT5</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">TEXT6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried the following:

```
#<tr[^>]*>(\r\n.*)*</tr>#
#<tr[^>]*>(.*?)*</tr>#
#<tr[^>]*>(.*)*</tr>#
```

And none of these seem to work. I need to get everything between
the  and  tags i.e. each row separately into an array.
Please help.

EDIT: I need to use REGEX as per requirements, so please don't suggest using the DOM PARSER.

Comment: You shouldn't attempt to parse html with regex.  Regex was not made to parse html.  Use a pre-existing library like php's DOMDocument.

Comment: Try: `$re = '%<tr[^>]*>(.*?)</tr>%is';` - But note that this won't work if you have nested tables.

Answer (score 1):

## Don't use Regex for parsing HTML files

Html is not strict..(for example sometimes html can have closing tags and sometimes it doesnt have it)

`Regex` is used for regular consistent expressions **not** irregular expressions

Use [DOMDocument->loadHTML()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to parse the HTML.

Believe me its damn simple to **parse** html than using `regex`

---

If you are ready to take the risk

Here is the regex for that

```
/<tr.*?>(.*?)</tr>/
```

Use `s`(PCRE_DOTALL) option

Comment: I know it is. However, due to strict requirements, I have to use regex.

Comment: @user1790263 check out the edit..use s option i.e dotall option to match

Comment: Your requirements don't make sense considering your task.

Comment: You might want to wrap the expression in `( )` to turn it into a capture group @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I have already tried it. The issue here is that LINE-BREAKS are not being ignored. Regex matching stops at line breaks. How do I overcome that?